# logitech wireless devices not recognized on Debian

Tags: linux, usb, debian, usb-3, debian-wheezy

I have a unifying receiver for mouse and keyboard. I am using Debian Wheezy on Asus UX31A.

The devices are recognized and working during boot and also in grub menu.

Once I get the Debian log in screen the devices no longer work. For it to work, I have to remove the unifying receiver and plug it again in usb port. I should do this few times then it works. I am doing this for few months now. However recently I have to spend more time in removing and plugging the unifying receiver. So thought I'll get some help. Below is the output from lspci and lsusb and right now the wireless mouse and keyboard are not working.

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 0153 (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
```

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bc2:2400 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card reader
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 04f2:b330 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
```

dmesg log when I unplu/plug the device couple of times

```
[ 5061.375849] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 5125.104450] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 5125.123495] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[ 5125.123506] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5125.123512] usb 1-2: Product: USB Receiver
[ 5125.123516] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 5125.127894] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.000B: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input2
[ 5125.128170] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.000B: logi_dj_probe:logi_dj_recv_query_paired_devices error:-32
[ 5125.128512] logitech-djreceiver: probe of 0003:046D:C52B.000B failed with error -32
[ 5200.838834] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 5226.982953] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 5227.002040] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[ 5227.002050] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5227.002056] usb 1-2: Product: USB Receiver
[ 5227.002060] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 5227.006761] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.000E: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input2
[ 5227.007042] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.000E: logi_dj_probe:logi_dj_recv_query_paired_devices error:-32
[ 5227.007315] logitech-djreceiver: probe of 0003:046D:C52B.000E failed with error -32
```

Comment: Can you show us the `dmesg` output when you plug/unplug the device?

Comment: dmesg gives me 1200 lines of output. Is there specific section of the output I need to post?

Comment: you can output the last 50.

Comment: @Braiam edited the question to include output from dmesg.